# dynamic fields for EF model ~ there has to be a better way

Tags: c#, dynamic, linq-to-entities

**Using** MVC5, EF6 Model First

**Issue at hand:** DYNAMIC ( user created ) Fields that i need to store in the database.

I've rammed my head against the internet all day today trying to get something better than writing alter table, update, and select commands for dynamic fields.

I don't believe that serializing the data and saving it is a great approach to this either.

**Do you guys have any better ideas / best practices you would like to share?**

Comment: You should really take this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ and expand your question so people know what the exact situation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to have an additional table that acts as the extension values that are defined by users. So if your main table is called **Customer** then it would have all the standard columns that are fixed. You would then have a table called **CustomerExtra** that stores the user defined fields for each customer row.

So if the user adds a user defined fields then you would need to add a row to the **CustomerExtra** table for each of the customer rows. Each of the rows would store the name of the user defined field as well as the value. To make that work the **CustomerExtra** would need columns for each of the types you allow the user to specify.

The advantage of this approach is you do not need to alter the schema of your database when new user defined fields are added or removed. This ensures the structure is the same for every client that buys and uses the system, even though each client sets up their own unique set of user defined fields.

The downside is the extra complexity in your queries and updates because of the need to interact with an additional column. This also adds a performance hit as well because you are querying against two tables instead of one.